# How to highlight a default menu even if you click any link outside nav?

Tags: jquery, css

To css and jquery gurus, I need your help :)
The title seems obscure so I try to explain by providing more details.

```
$("li a").filter(function(){ return this.href == location.href.replace(/#.*/, ""); }).parents('li').addClass("selected");
```

I am using the above code to highlight current page and its submenus.

My demo page [here](http://funr.net/play/).

If you click the link "This is a link outside nav", the "selected" class is gone.

How to make the "videos" menu selected by default even if I visit any link outside nav?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: In your PHP code (outsidelink.php) you should add the class 'selected' to your menu.

Comment: Hi sir, thanks for ur reply. I tried but it didn't work. Also I will be having lot's of links outside the nav area so adding each link with class seems not practical :)

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found a solution. I added the following jquery code on pages outside nav.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('nav ul li:first-child').addClass('selected');
});
```

The perfect solution maybe is using php but since I am doing this for design purposes only, I only used jquery. Hope this can be helpful to others as well.